# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'ximgproc'

Tags: python, opencv

I am having trouble using ximgproc in opencv on Jupyter notebook. I have my venv with the following pip package.

[image]

cv2.ximgproc is working when I run it in bash, but doesn't work on Jupyter notebook.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jupyter kernel is running a different version.

Examine `cv2.__version__` and `sys.path` to diagnose.

I installed cv2 4.5.5 into a project environment
from the conda-forge channel of anaconda.org,
and it worked great.
Take care to make the same environment available
when you run `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't install Jupyter notebook in the venv, so it opened the Jupyter notebook at the default environment. After I installed Jupyter notebook in my virtual environment and launched it, it worked!